# current week contains the last friday of the month

Tags: php

I am trying creating a script that will change an image on a page if the last friday in the month is during the current week. For example if I am on any of the day of week (Monday to Sunday) that contains the last friday of the month during the week I will get an output that differs from the rest of the month.

I was helped on a previous question with this code but it only works if the last day of the month is today. However I need the function to know if the last day of the month is on either Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday is still in the current week as my week runs from Monday to Sunday:

```
// Be sure to check your timezone `date_default_timezone_set`
$today       = new DateTime();
$last_friday = new DateTime('last Friday of this month');

// For testing
$friday_april = new DateTime('2014-4-25');

if ($today->format('Y-m-d') === $last_friday->format('Y-m-d')) {
  print 'Today is friday';
}

if ($friday_april->format('Y-m-d') === $last_friday->format('Y-m-d')) {
  print 'Yes, a test friday is also a friday';
}
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: `date('N', strtotime('last day of this month'))` will give you a 1(Monday) -> 7(Sunday) day value. From there's easy to calculate how far back the previous friday was.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, maybe I don't look logically enough :(

Comment: ok. Apr 2014 has last day = 30th, which is a wednesday. `date('N')` would return 3. If the last day was a Friday, date('N' would've returned a 5. `3 < 5` is true, so you need to go back to the previous friday: Wednesday -> Friday (going back in time) is 5 days: 3(Wed) -> 2(Tue) -> 1(Mon) -> 0(Sun) -> -1(sat) -> -2(fri). So Apr 30th  minus 5 days is Apr 25th, and there's your last friday in April. Same math would hold for going forward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your date format for the comparisons.

`W` should suffice.

**Why?!**

Because then the same string (the [ISO week number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date)) will be produced for dates within the same week (beginning on Mondays).

Given this month, April 2014, the week number of the week containing the last Friday is `17`.

```
2014-04-19 Sat => 16 ✗
2014-04-20 Sun => 16 ✗
2014-04-21 Mon => 17 ✓
2014-04-22 Tue => 17 ✓
2014-04-23 Wed => 17 ✓
2014-04-24 Thu => 17 ✓
2014-04-25 Fri => 17 ✓
2014-04-26 Sat => 17 ✓
2014-04-27 Sun => 17 ✓
2014-04-28 Mon => 18 ✗
2014-04-29 Tue => 18 ✗
2014-04-30 Wed => 18 ✗
```

**Summary**

```
if ($today->format('W') === $last_friday->format('W')) {
    // Do victory dance
}
```

Comment: Just tried this in May and it doesn't work but fantastic effort

Comment: I don't know what you tried, but it's fine for me: https://eval.in/private/b3868c92baff9c

Comment: If you want to restrict the days to within the same calendar month, you could use `mW`. Which for May 2014 would exclude Sunday June 1st, which technically belongs to the last week in May. Of course, your banner would only show for 6 days that week if you decided to go with `mW`.

Comment: Ow no sorry I was being an idiot in testing I still used DateTime('last Friday of this month'); for testing in May!! Sorry, you and your code rocks!

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop. Go through the loop and add a day until you get to the next month. Count how many Fridays you encounter (including today) from today to the start of the next month. If its only 1, then the last Friday is in this week.

Comment: Where's the best place to look into making loops as I haven't come across them before

Comment: Yeah I got no chance of learning how to do that anytime soon, but thank you - not because of lack of trying its just hard!

Answer (score 0):

use `strtotime` and `date` so it should look like this:

```
$today       = new DateTime();
$last_friday = strtotime('last Friday of this month');
// For testing
$friday_april = new DateTime('2014-4-25');

if ($today->format('Y-m-d') === date('Y-m-d', $last_friday)) {
  print 'Today is friday';
}

if ($friday_april->format('Y-m-d') === date('Y-m-d', $last_friday)) {
  print 'Yes, a test friday is also a friday';
}
```

Comment: @JosephGregory what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: if you checkout http://ng1club.everythingcreative.co.uk you'll see a banner from Monday to Sunday but the last Friday of the month shows a different event from a normal Friday so I need the new even to start showing from the Monday the last Friday of the month is on

Answer (score 0):

```
$today = getdate();
$weekStartDate = $today['mday'] - $today['wday'];
$weekEndDate = $today['mday'] - $today['wday']+6;
echo "week start date:".$weekStartDate;
echo "<br/>";
echo "week end date:".$weekEndDate;
```

By this code you can get start and end days of the current week

Answer (score 0):

```
$thisWeekHasLastFridayOfMonth = function () {
  $lastFridayThisMonth = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('last Friday of this month'));

  $testDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('today'));

  $thisWeekSunday = (date('N',strtotime($testDate))!=1?date('Y-m-d',strtotime('last Sunday')):date('Y-m-d'));
  $thisWeekSaturday = (date('N',strtotime($testDate))!=7?date('Y-m-d',strtotime('next Saturday')):date('Y-m-d'));

  //echo $lastFridayThisMonth . '<br>' . $thisWeekSunday . '<br>' . $thisWeekSaturday;
  if (strtotime($lastFridayThisMonth) >= strtotime($thisWeekSunday) &&
          strtotime($lastFridayThisMonth) <= strtotime($thisWeekSaturday))
    return true;
  else
    return false;
};

echo $thisWeekHasLastFridayOfMonth?'True':'False';
```

Comment: I have used date functions for easier debugging. You don't need them!

Comment: This isn't outputting anything on my php test page?

Comment: You need to insert this function somewhere in your code and call it from anywhere e.g. echo $thisWeekHasLastFridayOfMonth (it should return true or false)

Comment: I tried echo and its not doing anything and Dreamweaver is giving me a syntax error